# How to place grid items at the end of the container

Tags: html, css, gridview, css-grid

I have a grid container and I want my items to be placed at bottom.

I have this [Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFsKl.png)

I want something like this
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ITzG.png)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 8px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.item {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.item-1 {
  grid-column: span 5;
  grid-row: span 6;
}
.item-2 {
  grid-column: span 4;
  grid-row: span  5;
}
.item-3 {
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

PS: I've already tried place-items: end; and align-items: end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the two value `start / end` syntax for `grid-column` and `grid-row` to establish the start and end of your items.

For example `grid-row: 2 / span 3;` would start at the 2nd grid line and span an additional 3 more down to the 5th grid line.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 8px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.item {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.item-1 {
  grid-column: span 5;
  grid-row: span 6;
}
.item-2 {
  grid-column: 6 / span 4;
  grid-row: 2 / span 5;
}
.item-3 {
  grid-column: 10 / span 3;
  grid-row: 3 / span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Note: In response to the edit about `align-items`, this only works when the layout isn't being defined by spanning multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you Dan Carter!!

Comment: Happy to help. Can you mark this question as resolved please?